# How to broadcast a notification like same as database version?

Tags: laravel

I am loading notifications into the blade page with:

```
$user = auth()->user();
$notifications = $user->notifications()->get();

return view( 'notifications' );
```

So the page comes loaded with all existing notifications. Then I refresh the data on each incoming notification. 
But instead, I want to add each broadcasted notification to this page. The problem is that the broadcast comes different than the one I (initially) loaded.

the initially loaded data is like

```
created_at:"2019-06-18 12:41:52"
data:Object
id:"4dcd6e3c-2351-4e7f-a4fd-09eab7e56127"
notifiable_id:1
notifiable_type:"App\User"
read_at:null
type:"App\Notifications\TestNotification"
updated_at:"2019-06-18 12:41:52"
```

while the broadcast comes like

```
id:"31488065-f93e-41be-b79d-bd5590e52b41"
message:"This is a test message"
payload:"payload"
socket:null
status:"test"
title:"This is a test"
type:"App\Notifications\TestNotification"
```

because they are not the same I can't add (unshift) this broadcast into the initially loaded notifications. Instead, I have to refresh the initial data and update it. But this way each time a notification broadcast is received I load all the data. What I want instead is just add the incoming broadcast.

Any ideas of how I could do that on the go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around I figured out there is no easy way (without changing some core) to change this. So this is my (workaround) solution.

The initial data which loads the notification page comes from the database. Actually it is injected from a view Composer into blade view and from there into vue, thus it is global. Database notification format and broadcast notification format does not match. This was a big problem when it was tried to unshift(add) the latest incoming notification into the initial notification data because they were different. Despite the broadcast data the database data has a structure with additional created_at and data fields. Instead using the (already existing) incoming broadcast data, refetching the whole notification data from database was used. But it has a lot of disadvantages worth changing the structure. The major ones:

- it uses a lot traffic despite receiving just incoming broadcast data
- it additionally uses process for querying database
- the last incoming notification can't be animated easily
- additional time consume

So instead refetching all the notifications from database, the existing incoming broadcast data was adapted to the database format. Actually not all data but only the available and needed ones like:

```
            created_at: 'Yeni',
            data: {
                message: notification.message,
                payload: notification.payload,
                status: notification.status,
                title: notification.title,
            },
            id: notification.id,
```

Then it was possible to unshift this data to the existing initial database notifications.